# DDD in Scala: Should entities be immutable?

Tags: scala, domain-driven-design, immutability

In many java tutorials about DDD, entities are mutable objects.

```
class Product {  

    private String status;

    public void prepare() {
       this.status = "Prepearing"; 
    } 
}
```

In the example above, **prepare** method mutates the object's internal state.

But in scala, I'd like my entities to be immutable:

```
case class Product(status: String) {
    def prepare: Product = {
       this.copy(status = "Prepearing");
    }
}
```

So instead of mutating the object, I return back a new entity.

Is it ok in terms of DDD to have immutable entities and above implementation?

Or can you recommend a better approach?

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

> Should entities be immutable?

Yes, the probably should.  If I'm holding a reference to your object, and you change it, I should see those changes.  It's pretty much the reason that we use an entity rather than a value.

Review Vladimir Khorikov's post on [entities vs values](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/01/11/entity-vs-value-object-the-ultimate-list-of-differences/); [Jimmy Bogard](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/05/21/entities-value-objects-aggregates-and-roots/); [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EvansClassification.html)....

> Or can you recommend a better approach?

Create a separate concept for the *state* of the entity.  Let that state be a value object.

```
class Product {  

    private State state;

    public void prepare() {
        this.state = this.state.updateStatus("Preparing"); 
    } 
}
```

Stuart Halloways' talk on the [Clojure time model](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/An-Introduction-to-Clojure-Time-Model) helps to explain what's going on here; slide 31 in his [deck](https://qconsf.com/sf2010/dl/qcon-sanfran-2010/slides/StuartHalloway_PerceptionAndActionAnIntroductionToClojuresTimeModel.pdf) includes a good visualization of Identity as a succession of states.

Alternatively, you can abandon the OO approach altogether, and express the changes as pure functions

```
newState = theModel.prepare(oldState);
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question here, your product is mutable here (you are assigning a value to state). OP is talking about strict immutability (copy).

Answer (score 2):

In DDD, entities naturally exhibit different life cycle stages or states. In your example above, a product status can be 'Preparing', 'Fulfilling', 'Shipping', 'Out-For-Delivery' etc. Because of this life cycle, there is sometimes a temptation to model entities using the state pattern. Some DDD practitioners strongly discourage liberal use of the state pattern for entities. Reason being, it can lead to entity's methods side effecting. Side effects can make code harder to test and they can often be the source of bugs. The Product class above must be able to explicitly specify which state it needs to operate on. It cannot ship something that is not yet prepared and fulfilled.

Comment: Yes. Something you might want to take a look is the memento pattern - http://www.dofactory.com/net/memento-design-pattern